# Generate epoch time

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

I want to convert my time_stamp string into epoch time but I am not good with datetime and related modules, so getting a little confused. I saw many solutions but none of  them had date_time format like mine.

my date_time is in the below format
date_time  = "2023-01-1T17:35:19.818"

How can I convert this into epoch time using python?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With python 3.3+, you can try this:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2023-01-1T17:35:19.818", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").timestamp()
// 1672569319.818
```

First, I convert your datetime string to `datetime.datetime` object by using [strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) with your format `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"`.
Then I can just call `timestamp()` to convert it to epoch time

---

For older version of python, you can try

```
(datetime.datetime.strptime("2023-01-1T17:35:19.818", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f") - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
// 1672594519.818
```

I hope it help!

Comment: note the caveat here: since you do not specify a time zone / UTC offset, "2023-01-1T17:35:19.818" is take to represent *local time*, not UTC etc.